# Split a String in Microsoft Access SQL for use with a command parameter

Tags: sql, ms-access, .net-2.0

I am using Microsoft Access 2000, and need to pass in a parameter that is a comma-delimited string.  The comma-delimited string is for an IN clause of the where statement.  An example of this would be:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Field1 IN (@MyValues)
```

where @MyValues might be something like `1,2,3`

However, when I pass in `1,2,3` the Access parameter doesn't seem to accept the input.  Is there a good split string function in Access SQL that will solve this issue?  Or is there another way of tackling this problem?

For reference on what I am doing, I am trying to use parameterized SQL in .NET to get a result set.

**EDIT:**
Below is an example of some simplified .NET code that would call this query:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Field1 IN (@MyValues)");
cmd.Parameters.Add("@MyValues","1,2,3");
```

Comment: Access' Jet database engine does not support use of a parameter for `In (value list)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
  SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE @MyValues Like "%" & Field1 "%"
```

This should check to see if the value in the field is included as a substring of your @MyValues parameter. Now, this could be problematic if any of the individual values in @MyValues are substrings of each other:

```
  SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE "2, 5, 10" Like "%" & Field1 "%"
```

In that case, "1" in Field1 would match, but it shouldn't. So, it might be that you'd need to format the numbers or delimit them some other way, such as:

```
  SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE " 2 5 10 " Like "% " & Field1 " %"
```

Or, alternatively:

```
  SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ", 2, 5, 10," Like "%, " & Field1 ",%"
```

I'm not sure how this would perform, but it at least would allow parameterization.

Comment: A simple and effective solution.  The only caveat, as you point out, is if any of your search terms are substrings of each other.  If that's not a problem for the OP, then this is the best way to go.

Comment: This seems like the most elegant solution.  I'm still concerned about performance, but like you said it does allow for parameterization.

Answer (score 1):

At first, your question looked a little familiar.  Then it started looking REALLY familiar.  Then I realized I had the same question not long ago.  My solution was to toss the parameters into this function:

```
Public Function IsIn( _
  ByVal value As Variant, _
  ParamArray theset() As Variant) _
  As Boolean

  Dim i As Long
 
  For i = LBound(theset) To UBound(theset)
    If value = theset(i) Then
      IsIn = True
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next
End Function
```

In your sample SQL code, you could do something like:

```
 SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE IsIn(Field1,array(1,2,3))=true;
```

(Like you, I also think that a procedure like this one should have been built into Access. Perhaps it is in 2007 or 2010.)

### Edit

See [Is there a NotIn("A","B") function in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764523/is-there-a-notina-b-function-in-vba)

Comment: This looks very interesting.  Do you know the execution plan?  From the looks of your function it would get all from Table1 and then loop through the entire table to do the filter comparison.  That seems like it could be costly since it is bypassing the database engines query structure.

Comment: Well, I suppose the query would run this procedure for every record in Table1.  If your array is pulled from a separate table, then Access would have to pull that data once for each record in Table1.  In that case, performance may be an issue.  But if your array is relatively small and stored in the query itself, it shouldn't take too long.

Comment: If you're using .Net to connect to an MDB, your query can not use a user-defined function which was created in the MDB.

Comment: @HansUp, if that's an issue, then the OP could make a temporary local table of the final dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put them in another table and do a join?

If you don't want to create another table, that's ok.  What does your ADO code and query syntax look like?

From your edited code above, I don't think you need to use the cmd object's parameters collection.  Just modify your sql to embed your parameter values:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Field1 IN (1,2,3)");
```

You would use the .parameters collection if you had a parametrized query in the mdb, which you don't.  Your sql is in source code.

Comment: I wouldn't want to create another table for this.  That would complicate what should be a simple solution.

Comment: Added the ADO code for you above.  It's simplified from the actual code, but should get the point across.

Comment: While that solution will work, there are some architectural goals I would like to use which is why I want to use parameterized SQL.  Namely I am moving all SQL strings to a Resources library so that no SQL resides directly in a class, and I can copy the code into Access to verify that the SQL works.

Comment: You use parametrized SQL with parametrized queries.  I would keep the sql in the mdb.